# Hello. I am coding a music quiz game in Python. Correct answers are not authenticated, and I have no idea why

Tags: python, file

My music quiz game takes a list of songs from an external file named 'Songs.txt' and takes the first letter of each word in one song (out of 7, picked randomly) and then displays the artist of that song. The user then has two guesses, and the appropriate points are then awarded:

```
# MUSIC QUIZ GAME

import random
# Import the 'random' function in order to select a random number and get a random song.
import time
# Importing the ability to 'pause' to give the program a more professional feel.
import sys
# Import the ability to close the program.
import linecache
# Import the ability to get a specific line from a file.

userscore = 0
# The userscore is automatically zero, because they have just started playing.

random_picker = random.randint(1,7)
# Using the random operator, we pick a random number from 1 to 5, because there are 5 songs. We will use this to select the same random line from two files.
# ----- Accessing the Songs database ----- #
     # Open the file.
file = open("Songs.txt", "r")
     # Get the line from file. The line number is determined by the 'random_picker' used earlier.
song = linecache.getline(r"Songs.txt", random_picker).upper()
     # Split the line into individual words.
song_prompt = song.split()

# ----- Accessing the Artists database ----- #
file = open("Artists.txt", "r")
artist = linecache.getline(r"Artists.txt", random_picker)

# -----Giving the user the prompt ----- #
print("\nYour prompt is: ")

# Get only the first letter of each word in the prompt, then output them.
for word in song_prompt:
    print(word[0])
print("by " + artist)

guess1 = input("Enter your song name guess:\n")

if guess1 == song:
     print("Well done!")
     userscore = userscore + 3
     print("Your score is " + str(userscore) + ".")
  
elif guess1 != song:
     print("Wrong guess.")
     guess2 = input("What is your second guess for the song name?\n")
     
     if guess2 == song:
          print("Well done.")
          userscore = userscore + 1
          print("Your score is " + str(userscore) + ".")
     else:
          print("You have gotten both guesses wrong.")
          sys.exit()
```

However, on both guesses, with the right song, uppercase, lowercase, capitilised titles, etc, the software always deems the answer wrong. Is it to do with the way the file is read? I'm not quite sure. If anyone could help me with this issue, that would be much appreciated.

The 'Songs.txt' file contains this list:

```
Let It Happen
New Gold
Shotgun
Metamodernity
Bad Guy
Blank Space
Bohemian Rhapsody
```

The 'Artists.txt' file contains this list:

```
Tame Impala
Gorillaz
George Ezra
Vansire
Billie Eillish
Taylor Swift
Queen
```

For example, the quiz says:

```
Your prompt is: 
N
G
by Gorillaz

Enter your song name guess:
New Gold
Wrong guess.
What is your second guess for the song name?
NEW GOLD
You have gotten both guesses wrong.
```

I am expecting to get the correct answer.

Comment: Do the song strings end in new lines still? I.e `== song.strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might *also* have an issue with the way you read the .txt files.

When you run the following line: `song = linecache.getline(r"Songs.txt", random_picker).upper()`

The value assigned to `song` will be something like `'LET IT HAPPEN\n'`

In order to avoid this you can use the .rstrip() method:

```
song = linecache.getline(r"Songs.txt", random_picker).upper().rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Hi trym, thanks for your comment. I have implemented this reading method and it works great. Thank you.